# Can we replace ref with className or id in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning refs. As far as I found out, refs are used to reference a certain tag in a component but the question is Can't we just use className or id instead of ref? Are there any benefits of ref and that className or id cannot provide?

Comment: check this solution for your questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/58601129/6544460

Answer (score 0):

**When to Use Refs** - [Reactjs Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

There are a few good use cases for refs:

- Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
- Triggering imperative animations.
- Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

**One of multiple reasons**

Assuming that you went ahead and used an ID to access one of your elements in a React .component

```
onFocus() {
        document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute("class", "highlight");
      }

      onBlur() {
        document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute("class", "");
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              id="myInput"
              onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this)}
              onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        );
    }
```

This would actually work.

**The Reusability Problem**

- The problem you'll encounter is with re-usability.
- When you try to create that same component multiple times
- You can create multiple input with same refs.

For you better understanding [Difference](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/use-refs-not-ids/)

Comment: @Dickens check now and read bullet points that you can't do with id or className. I hope it will clear your questions.

Comment: Can't we achieve Managing focus, text selection, or media playback. with className as well?

Comment: @Dickens have you achieved media playback, reusability of objects using className?